# Django order by count

Tags: django

I have these models:

```py
class Project(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=80)
    date_created=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
```

And this in views:

```py
cat_list = Category.objects.order_by(order_by)
for c in cat_list:
    count = Project.objects.filter(category__id=c.id).count()
    setattr(c, 'count', count)
```

How can I now order this by COUNT attribute?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The proper way to do this is with [annotation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/). This will reduce the amount of database queries to 1, and ordering will be a simple `order_by` function:

```
from django.db.models import Count

cat_list = Category.objects.annotate(count=Count('project_set__id')).order_by('count')
```