# drf filter with related table count

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Here is my model:

```
    class Artwork(models.Model):
        id                = models.BigAutoField(primary_key = True)
        serial            = models.IntegerField(choices=Serial.choices, default=100)
        title             = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
        slug              = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)


    class Views(models.Model):
        id        = models.BigAutoField(primary_key = True)
        user    = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="views")
        artwork = models.ForeignKey(Artwork, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="views")
```

Here is my view

```
    class GetArtworkLiteView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        queryset = Artwork.objects.all()
        serializer_class = GetArtworkLiteSerializer

        filter_backends = [filters.OrderingFilter, DjangoFilterBackend]
        filterset_fields = ['slug']
        ordering_fields = ["id", "serial"]
```

Here i want to make ordering by count(views) in artwork model.
How can i add logic to that so artwork model will sort by count of views
i wants to implement this using django rest framework

Comment: Does this solution help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23033769/django-order-by-count

Comment: No. this is breaking drf staandard

Comment: ```queryset = Artwork.objects.annotate(count=Count('views_set__id')).order_by('count')```

Comment: How can i get this in descending order ?

Comment: use ```order_by('-count')```

Comment: i am getting error django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword

Comment: hm, I just tried it in my project and it worked...could you please post the full error message? Did you import the Count function as done in the linked solution?

Comment: if this solved your initial question, please be so kind to mark my response as correct answer, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
queryset = Artwork.objects.annotate(count=Count('views')).order_by('-count')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply the sorting to your view's queryset. The sorting itself should work regardless of using DRF or not.

Change your view class:

```
    from django.db.models import Count

...

    class GetArtworkLiteView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        queryset = Artwork.objects.annotate(count=Count('views_set__id')).order_by('count')
        serializer_class = GetArtworkLiteSerializer

        filter_backends = [filters.OrderingFilter, DjangoFilterBackend]
        filterset_fields = ['slug']
        ordering_fields = ["id", "serial"]
```